# Why is the App Insight LogLevel in appsettings being ignored?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, appinsights

We use `ILogger` in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 website, using the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` package, version 2.14. We are trying to enable the logging of informational messages into App Insight, e.g., `_logger.LogInformation("info here")`.

In our startup in `ConfigureServices`, we enable App Insights:

```cs
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

We have the following in our appsettings.json file:

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
        "InstrumentationKey": "12345678-1234-5678-1234-1234567890ab",
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
    }
}
```

It picks up the app insight key correctly (we do get the normal metrics, and log entries such as exceptions), however none of our calls to `logger.LogInformation("Info here")` are being sent/recorded in the App Insight dashboard.

I found this question which is similar:

[ILogger Not Respecting Log Level for Application Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657398/ilogger-not-respecting-log-level-for-application-insights)

But the answer still doesn't really address how to be able to change the log level from the appsettings.json file vs. hard-coding the log level into the code.

It seems like, from the docs, this should "just work", but it doesn't appear to.

[Application Insights logging with .NET](https://%EF%BB%BFhttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#control-logging-level)

Where are we going wrong?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You've got the `LogLevel` property for `ApplicationInsights` in the wrong place. Here's what it should look like:

```json
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
    }
},
"ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "12345678-1234-5678-1234-1234567890ab"    
}
```

The log-level configuration lives under the `Logging` parent, but the `InstrumentationKey` lives outside of that hierarchy.

See [Configure logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#configure-logging) in the official ASP.NET Core docs for more about provider-specific configuration.