# Serilog's Application Insight sink does not put the right Severity Level on Azure Application Insights when logging errors or warnings

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights, serilog

We have a .NET 6.0 Azure Function App (dotnet-isolated) whose Serilog's configuration is per the following entry in the appsettings.json file:

```json
"Serilog": {
        "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" ],
        "WriteTo": [
            {
                "Name": "Console",
                "Args": {
                    "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
                    "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <s:{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Exception}",
                    "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
                "Args": {
                    "instrumentationKey": "MASKED-KEY",
                    "telemetryConverter": MyTelemetryConverter, My",
                    "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"
                }
            }
        ],
        "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
        "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Override": {
                "Microsoft": "Information",
                "System": "Information"
            }
        }
    }
```

The following C# extension method reads this configuration entry in the function app's Program.cs file at the startup time:

```cs
    public static IHostBuilder UseLogger(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
    {
        hostBuilder.ConfigureLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, DefaultLoggerProvider>());
        hostBuilder.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration));
        return hostBuilder;
    }
```

`ILogger` interface is perfectly available all across the application, and we can log different messages to the AI, for example:

```cs
_logger.LogError("My fictitious error message here");
```

The error message is logged, but its severity level is registered as "Information" instead of "Error". This issue applies to warnings too.

This is how the log appears on the AI:

[image]

The [6:25:36 ERR] text in the screenshot above proves that the message was logged as an error per the formatting configuration found in the appsettings.json file. Also please note that the MyTelemetryConverter implementation does not interfere with log levels at all.

*Note: Logging exceptions works fine.*

**UPDATE: June 17th, 2022:**

The `Convert(...)` override method in the derived class from `TraceTelemetryConverter` carries the proper severity level per the following screenshot:

[image]

What may be wrong in this configuration and how to fix it?

Comment: I have a feeling there's some support for telemetry converters in the sink, that can be customized for this kind of thing. I'm not familiar enough with it to be able to answer in full though, sorry.

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt at least the github issue could have stayed open to get some answer through it!

Comment: Added a screenshot.